# Цикл While не ждет сообщение введенное пользователем

Tags: python, telebot, while

Пользователь должен ввести свой возраст, если вдруг его сообщение будет являться строкой, то бот напишет: "Вводите только число", после бот снова записывает сообщение пользователя.
В этом и весь цикл. Проблема только в том, что Питон бесконечно спамит заданное ему сообщение, пока пользователь не введет число, спамит сообщение "Вводите только число", как это исправить ?

```
import telebot

age = 0

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == '/reg':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пишите свой возраст')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_age)

def reg_age(message):
    global age
    while age == 0:
        try:
            age = int(message.text)
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вводите только число')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_age)
```

Comment: Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать этим циклом? Почему вы считаете, что в процессе обработки одного сообщения его содержимое может измениться?

Answer (score 1):

```
def reg_age(message):
  if message.text.isdigit():
     # здесь у тебя точно в месседж тексте будет число
     ...
  else:
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вводите только число')
     bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_age)
```